A confusion of the index of Pauli matrix
Maybe the question is not easy to describe clearly, so let's consider a concrete question, which is a common exercise in Majorana Fermion: Prove $$\psi_L^T \sigma_2 \psi_L$$ is Lorentz invariant.
In the standard step we just check $S^T \sigma_2S=\sigma_2$.
But I wonder, there the "2" seems like a component of $\sigma_\mu$, where $\mu$ is a vector index, so why here we don't need to impose a vector Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^\nu_2$ to transform the middle $\sigma_2$ matrix.
And the Pauli matrices seem to carry 1 vector index and 2 spinor index, can we just prove the question by explicitly showing that there exists some index contraction, which is Lorentz invariant.

Linked.

Consider writing the Ss explicitly in terms of Pauli matrices... Which text did they come out of?
